# Graphical intuition of why the integral is a linear operator

Tags: integration, linear-transformations, graphing-functions, intuition

so I can prove using upper and lower riemansums why the integral is a linear operator:

$$\int a f(x) + b g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = a\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + b\int g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

And I also understand why it intuitively must be true, as I know that integration
and derivation are inverse operations and since the latter is linear the former also has to be.

Graphically I can also understand why a sum of integrals must be the integral of each function
$\int (f+g) = \int f + \int g$. However I struggle to understand the graphical implications of the scaling. E.g.

- Is there some graphical intuition why
  $$ \int a \cdot f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = a \int f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$$ holds ?

I tried to graph the above statement for $f(x)=x^2$ on the interval $x \in [0,1]$

[image]

However, I can not intuitively say why the green area is twice as big as the green one.

Comment: from a geometric viewpoint, the height of the rectangle whose upper left vertex is at $(1,1)$ gets scaled up by a factor of $2$. This means that it’s area doubles. The rest of the green area is close to the shape of a right triangle, and it’s height also gets scaled up by a factor of two. This means that it’s area doubles. I presume a similar approach would work for other functions.

Comment: You said that you do understand intuitively that $\int (f+g) = \int f + \int g$. Alright, so what's the purple area? Clearly, that's $\int 2f - \int f$, right? Therefore you intuitively know that it's the same as $\int 2f-f = \int f$. And voila, purple area same as green one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if one imagines $a f(x)$ as being $a$ copies of $f(x)$ stacked on top of each other?

Then the integral of $a f(x)$ would be $a$ integrals performed “side by side”. With $a$ copies of the area, one can intuit that the cumulative area is $a$ times the original area.